# Internal errors on fresh 16.04 install

Tags: 16.04

I wiped and installed 16.04 twice, and I'm getting a series of internal errors after switching to the nvidia drivers. This is the current one showing, but not the only one:

[image: ubutu 16.04 internal error message]

Comment: That error is related to Network Manager. In fact, the problem is with nm-apple (the little 'icon' on the top bar for network connections).
There's a bug related [here](http://%20https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/network-manager-applet/+bug/1581979) Could you check if you have installed (and up to date) the package 'gnome-keyring'?

Comment: @Rahul there's no reason to suggest that at this point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Running

```
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

resolved the issue, which I'm going to assume also upgraded `gnome-keyring` and everything else that was causing the other internal errors.